# while using server sent events browser caching previous data. How to prevent browser caching

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, eve

My code is show bellow.I am using pythoneve flask angularjs.

```
def testing():
    message = "hai"
    yield 'data: %s\n\n' % message


@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    return flask.Response(testing(),mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

Comment: Is this any help http://arusahni.net/blog/2014/03/flask-nocache.html ?

Comment: no It does not helped for me

Comment: My angularjs request is show in bellow answered comment

Answer (score 3):

You can do it either on client or server side, here's how:

On the client side (browser), the simplest would be tacking on a query parameter to your request, i.e.

```
$http.get('/stream?b=123456');
```

where 123456 is a random string, can be a timestamp in milliseconds. Random parameter would force a browser to resend the request and not use its cache.

OR on the server-side, you would send special cache-control headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Either of these should do the trick, just make sure you implement it correctly in a language you use.

Comment: my code is show bellow. above solution did not work out.                                               var source = new EventSource('/stream');
                                                       source.onmessage = function (event) {
                                                        if(parseInt(event.data)){
                                                                     console.log(event.data)
$scope.searchActivity = new SearchActivity(user);
}
};

Comment: You need to do what I said above on the client side, in the browser. If you talking server side only, you have to send a special cache header to avoid caching. I'll have to look that up though. So, do you want to control cache from the server side or client side?

Comment: actually after getting response from server to browser did not update data. it showing preivous data. while I am doing ctrl+shift+delete cache was cleared. after that it showing correct data. So want I need to do ? Is it serverside problem or cliend side?

Comment: server sent events return true if any database update operation done. then after I am sending get request from browser to server using python eve api. But did not getting updated value.Instead getting previous value. after ctlr+shift+delete getting updated value through get request. url used for get request is http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/searchActivity.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include server-side, but on the client it's much easier to implement. See what works better for you.

Comment: how to set and where i need to set those headers in above stream view.

Comment: I'm not a python guy, so I don't know. But as a developer you should be able to figure it out how to add http headers to the response. Good luck!

Comment: this time i got your useful answer with the help of my friend. vary thank friend.